# What do you think of the new FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

Okay, so after much discussion on how to move our site to the next level and focus on quality and community engagement, I've revised our FAQ to make it much more concise.

While the previous revision [had it's problems](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/do-we-need-to-include-general-reference-in-the-faq), one thing we did learn from all of our discussions is what the site is not about, which is pretty important!

Following the lead of [Super User's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), here is our updated FAQ:

> ## What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> The site is for project management practitioners, academics and amateur theorists. This is a site about the field of project management for people who love the subject. Our site includes the following topics:
>
> ***This site is about...***
>
> - Project Management Practices and Theory
> - Agile
> - Scrum
> - PRINCE2
> - Tool Usage in Project Management
> - Project Manager Career Advancement
>
> ***This site is NOT about...***
>
> - Recommendations for blogs, books, links, or general terminology. (Just take a look at our top users' profiles! Many of them maintain popular, knowledgeable blogs)
> - Tool recommendations
> - General workplace issues (See The Workplace SE)
>
> Project Management Stack Exchange is a community-run Q&A site, run by the community, with rigorous discussions about the site itself taking place on our Project Management Meta. Welcome to our site!

So, what did I miss?  What else needs to go in the "What this site is about" category?  What needs to go in the "What this site is not about" category?

Comment: It should be `top users' profiles` unless we only have one top user with many profiles. :)

Comment: Good eye @CodeGnome! Fixed (in both the real faq and here). I hate typos. ;)

Comment: Hi @TiagoCardoso, you should add that as an answer so people can vote on it and respond in the comments.

Comment: You spelled "management" wrong in the line "Tool Usage in Project Panagement".

Comment: Thanks @ThomasOwens! I'll take a minute to proofread this again in greater detail when my crazy day comes to a conclusion! I'm usually better at proofreading than this. :)

Answer (score 3):

In `This site is about...`, I would recommend to replace:

> - Project Management Practices and Theory
> - Agile
> - Scrum
> - PRINCE2

with:

> - Project management approaches, including:
>
>   - Agile project management
>
>     - Scrum
>     - Kanban
>   - Critical chain project management (CCPM)
>   - Event chain methodology
>   - Extreme project management (XPM)
>   - Lean project management
>   - PRINCE2
>   - PRiSM
>   - Process-based management

This will give wider/specific range of topics that're definitely relate to PM.

reference: [List of project management topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_project_management_topics)

Comment: Do you think Scrum still needs to fit in there somewhere, or do you think it's implied just by the fact that Agile is included?

Comment: Exactly, Scrum is included in Agile.

Comment: @jmort253 Scrum and Kanban are distinct processes, and I wouldn't hand-wave it with "agile." Lots of folks think they're "doing agile," but they are certainly not doing Scrum or Kanban. "Agile frameworks such as Scrum or Kanban" might be a suitable replacement, though, if you want to be more inclusive of other possibilities.

Comment: I added that in to Rami's answer, @CodeGnome.

Comment: well, if mentioning Scrum and Kanban, why not mentioning all [Agile methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development#Agile_methods). I think we need to balance between too general and too specific.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent. Big thumbs up from me!

I see from the FAQ edit history that you've put a lot of time into helping define and grow this site. Thank you for that!

I hope you find the concise format more useful and flexible. As the site grows and evolves, it gives you a bit of elbow room to adapt and evolve the message you want to pass on to first time users. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe explode '*PM practices and theory*'?

There are 'actions' that could be made more explicit, like the tags we have, as 'common project problems', 'risk management', 'project planning' and so on.

For the seasoned community members isn't hard to understand what 'practices and theory' refers to, but it may not happen for the new visitors... no?

Comment: I kind of have a problem with the "common-project-problems" tag. See [this list of removeable tags](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/a/408/34) for more information.... The other tags you list are great, and listing some common tags as example topics might not be a bad idea. My only concern is in making the FAQ too long and too hard to read. If you have some text in mind, please add that to your answer. I tend to be long-winded and welcome some more specific input. Thank you! :)